# Adding parenthesis in 'IF' statement

Tags: cobol

I have a question concerning the use of parenthesis in IF statements in COBOL.

Let's say we have :

```
05 SHIRT-COLOR  PIC X(02).
   88 BLUE-SHIRT   VALUE 'B '.
   88 WHITE-SHIRT  VALUE 'W '.
```

I would like to know if there is a difference between :

```
IF BLUE-SHIRT OR WHITE-SHIRT
```

and

```
IF (BLUE-SHIRT OR WHITE-SHIRT)
```

Will the two IF statements give the same result or not?

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Yes it’s the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the parentheses make no difference, but it is perhaps important to understand what is going on here semantically and syntactically.

In COBOL the `IF` statement expression *is not* enclosed in parentheses.  However an *expression* may use parentheses to force a particular evaluation order.  So in this case it is simply an expression with redundant parentheses.  That is to say the expressions:

```
(BLUE-SHIRT OR WHITE-SHIRT)
```

and

```
BLUE-SHIRT OR WHITE-SHIRT
```

that are semantically identical and the `IF` is irrelevant.

Comment: And the reason COBOL doesn’t need parentheses here is because it has the THEN keyword instead.

Comment: To expand on the thought: if the expression you are testing is complicated, you might want to force a particular order of testing the values.  For instance IF SHIRT-SIZE > 10 AND (BLUE-SHIRT OR WHITE-SHIRT).